How to make the return value not to contain any punctuation
Create a function  that will encode any given string into a compressed form! Have the function RebelEncoding(string str) take a string parameter and return the encoded string, The returned value must not contain any punctuation.
static string RebelEncoding(string str)
{
  
    if (str == null || str == "")
    {
        return str;
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    char prevChar = str[0]; 
    int count = 1;
    for(int i = 1;i < str.Length;i++)
    {
        if (!Char.IsPunctuation(str[i]))
        {
          
            if (str[i] == prevChar)
            {
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append(count);
                sb.Append(prevChar);
                prevChar = str[i];
                count = 1;
            }  
        }
    }
    sb.Append(count);
    sb.Append(prevChar);
    string results = sb.ToString();
    if (results.Length >= str.Length)
    {
       return results;
    }
    return results;

}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string results;
    results=RebelEncoding("Squad Beta-111 attack!");
    Console.WriteLine(results);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

My output:
1S1q1u1a1d1 1B1e1t1a311 1a2t1a1c1k
Desired output:
1S1q1u1a1d 1B1e1t1a31 1a2t1a1c1k

This isn't Java.

Rolled back. It was someone else that incorrectly tagged it as Java. It's actually C#.

@Codebling Why did you mark this with the [tag:java] tag? (I wonder why so many unicorns edits here...)

It is encoding the spaces. Try with "AAA   BBB" to make it easier to see. Do you not want that?

If you want a certain output as you show it might help if show also the input for that example output.

@Ralf It's there in the code: results=RebelEncoding("Squad Beta-111 attack!");.

You also must test for white spaces that don't count as puncutation: !Char.IsPunctuation(str[i]) && !Char.IsWhiteSpace(str[i])

@user85421 OP is new contributor, tags were clearly wrong (rle?). Quick glance was too quick, moot because clearly a homework question.

@Codebling the tags were not wrong at all. The rle tag was indeed relevant because the task involved run length encoding.

I just added && str[i] != ' ' condition to your if statement, since the problem was with whitespaces in your string.
and also added else if (str[i] == ' ') logic for when it reaches white spaces.
for(int i = 1;i < str.Length;i++)
{
    if (!Char.IsPunctuation(str[i]) && str[i] != ' ')
    {      
        if (str[i] == prevChar)
        {
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(count);
            sb.Append(prevChar);
            prevChar = str[i];
            count = 1;
        }  
    }
    else if (str[i] == ' ')
    {
        sb.Append(count);
        sb.Append(prevChar);
        sb.Append(' '); // Append space character
        while (i + 1 < str.Length && str[i + 1] == ' ')
        {
            i++;
        }
        prevChar = i + 1 < str.Length ? str[i + 1] : ' ';
        count = 0;
    }
}


Use below to clean your string:
string cleanStr = Regex.Replace(str, @"[^\w\s]", "");


As this is an answer not just a comment how does this get us from the input to the desired output?

It would have been more in the spirit of the question to suggest if ( !(Char.IsPunctuation(str[i]) || Char.IsWhiteSpace(str[i])) ).
